# Fantasy book from the 1980s or 1990s about the rise and fall of empires

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to remember the name of a series of books I read during the late 90s.  I believed the details of the story were that it spanned hundreds of years and followed the rise and fall of empires that were in part Middle Eastern influenced.  Also I think some of the characters were particularly long lived.  Anyone have any thoughts or possible suggestions?

Comment: rojomoke was able to answer my question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This could be Glen Cook's "Dread Empire" series, where two immortals play a very long-term game with the peoples of the world, subtly influencing them in various ways to score points off each other.  One of them causes a desert nomad to become a fanatical Prophet, sparking a whole new militant religion obviously based on Islam.

Comment: Yes, that's it!  I remember now I had just finish reading some of the Black Company and picked up the Dread Empire books because I became a fan of Glen Cook.  Thanks so much!  This has been bugging me for weeks.  You're awesome!

Comment: You're welcome.  Feel free to click on the tick symbol to "accept" my answer.